# Fixed y-axis length in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, graph, chart.js, linechart

I am using https://www.chartjs.org/

I have multiple data to plot different line chart

I need to set stepSize: 10 for y axis with fixed length ( example 20px)  for all line chart

I mean  length of each step same for all plot (0 to 10= 20px, 10 to 20= 20px)

could you please help me on this?

```
<canvas id="myFirstChart"></canvas>
<canvas id="mySecondChart"></canvas>

var ctx = document.getElementById('myFirstChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',


    data: {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'First Chart',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [0, 100, 50, 20, 200, 30, 45]
        }]
    },

        options: {
            responsive: false,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                        stepSize: 10
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
});

var ctx = document.getElementById('mySecondChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',


    data: {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Second Chart',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [10, 40, 60, 70, 50, 90, 65]
        }]
    },

        options: {
            responsive: false,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                        stepSize: 10
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
});
```

Thanks